# Oracle Query Update From

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder if I can do this query in Oracle database?

```
UPDATE
    Table_A SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2 FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

this is working on sql server (microsoft). but cant work in oracle db. could you please tell me the reason ?

Comment: I was asking the reason

Comment: The reason is - "Oracle developers didn't implement the feature in this way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use merge into in Oracle.

```
MERGE Into Table_A t USING Table_B s
           ON (t.id = s.id)
        when matched then UPDATE SET
    t.col1 = s.col1, t.col2 = s.col2   
       WHERE t.col3 = 'cool'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
UPDATE table_a SET table_a.col1 = (SELECT table_B.COl1
                                  FROM table_B 
                                  WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id),
                   table_a.col2 = (SELECT table_B.COl2
                                  FROM table_B 
                                  WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id)
WHERE table_a.col3='cool';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which might work:

```
UPDATE 
(
    SELECT a.col1 AS col1a, a.col2 AS col2a, b.col1 AS col1b, b.col2 AS col2b
    FROM Some_Table a
    INNER JOIN Other_Table b
        ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.col3 = 'cool'
) t
SET
    a.col1a = b.col1b,
    a.col2a = b.col2b;
```

If Oracle doesn't want to run the above, then you will have to use correlated subqueries.